# Options for using PHP and HTML Input select

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm developing a system and it has two selects with options.

```html
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="area">area:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="area">
            <option>Select...</option>
            <option>Technician</option>
            <option>Administration</option>
            <option>Programming</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Category">Category:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="Category" required>
            <option>Select...</option>
            <option>Computing</option>
            <option>Hardware</option>
          </select>
        </div>
</form>
```

the fields are fictitious but I would like to see a certain field appear when the user chooses, in case if he chooses administration everything appears corresponding to the administration in the category below, if he chooses technical area everything appears about the technical area and so on, how can I do this ?

Comment: Use Ajax / JQuery to trap the change event on the first drop-down menu, call a bit of PHP (or anything) code to generate the options for the second menu based on that selection, and insert them into your document model on return from the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an example, when you select an option at the first select will create in the second select only what you want.

```js
function Check(val){
  removeOptions(document.getElementById('category'));
  var element=document.getElementById('area');
  if(val=='Technician'){
  var select = document.getElementById("category");
  var option1 = document.createElement("option");
  option1.text = "Hardware";
  option1.value = "hardware";
 
  select.add(option1);

  
 }else if(val=='Programming'){
  
  var select = document.getElementById("category");
  var option1 = document.createElement("option");
  option1.text = "Computing";
  option1.value = "Computing";
 
  select.add(option1);

  }
  }
  function removeOptions(selectElement) {
  var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
  for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
   selectElement.remove(i);
  }
 }
```

```html
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="area">area:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="area" id="area" onchange='Check(this.value);'>
            <option>Select...</option>
            <option>Technician</option>
            <option>Programming</option>
            
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Category">Category:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="Category" id="category" placeholder="Select first Area" required>
            
          </select>
        </div>
</form>
```